# Syncronization issue between two running threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue, synchronization

This is a partial solution to the single lane bridge problem that says that only cars that move at the same direction can be on the bridge at the same time. So it makes sense since it a single lane bridge that a car moving from left to right, should not be on the bridge at the same time that another car is moving from right to left. While Ive used locks and queues (one for leftbound and one for right bound traffic), cars that move at opposite directions end up crossing the bridge at the same time, and I don't know why because the locks and the logic ardound them should prevent that from happening.

I was hopping that the logic I have added inside the `cross_bridge()` method would ensure that cars moving towards the opposite direction do not end up on the bridge at the same time.

This is my code up to this point:

```
import threading, queue
from threading import Lock
from random import randint
import random
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase
import time

q = queue.Queue(3)
ql = queue.Queue(3)
carsList = []
cnt = 0
cntL = 0
lc = []
rc = []
has_lock_a = -1
has_lock_b = -1
has_lock_c = -1

class Car:
    def __init__(self, t_arrive, direction, name, idx):
        self.t_arrive = t_arrive
        self.direction = direction
        self.name = name
        self.idx = idx
        self.currDir = 0
    def __str__(self):
        return "Car(name: " + self.name + ", time: " + str(self.t_arrive) + ", direction: " + str(self.direction) + ")\n"


class Bridge:

    def __init__(self):
        self.threads = []
        self.threadCnt = 0
        self.cntL = 0
        self.cnt = 0
        self.rc_nt = 0
        self.lock_a = Lock()
        self.lock_b = Lock()
        self.lock_c = Lock()
        self.sem = threading.Semaphore(0)
        self.capacity = 3
        self.dir = -1

    def workerR(self):
        while True:
            itemR = q.get()
            print(itemR)
            if rc:
                index = rc.pop(0)
                self.arrive_bridge(carsList[index], index)
                while self.dir != -1 or self.dir == 1:
                    print("hs")
                    pass
                self.lock_a.acquire()
                self.cross_bridge(carsList[index], index)

                self.exit_bridge(carsList[index])

                self.rc_nt += 1
            q.task_done()
            self.sem.release()

    def workerL(self):
        while True:
            self.sem.acquire()
            itemL = ql.get()
            print(itemL)
            if lc:
                index = lc.pop(0)

                self.arrive_bridge(carsList[index], index)
                while self.dir != -1 or self.dir == 0:
                    pass
                self.lock_a.acquire()
                self.cntL += 1
                self.cross_bridge(carsList[index], index)
                self.exit_bridge(carsList[index])
            ql.task_done()
            self.sem.release()

    def arrive_bridge(self, car: Car, cnt):
        print(car.name + " arrived at bridge\n")



    def cross_bridge(self, car: Car, cnt):
        lock_ac = 0
        print(car.name + " crossing bridge\n")
        oneFourth = car.t_arrive / 4
        for i in range(4):
            if i == 2:
               self.lock_b.acquire()
               self.dir = car.direction
               self.lock_a.release()
            time.sleep(oneFourth)

        self.lock_b.release()
        # time.sleep(car.t_arrive)


    def exit_bridge(self, car: Car):
        print(car.name + " Exiting bridge\n")
        self.dir = -1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # first (i), (ii), (iii)
    totalNumberOfCars = randint(8, 11)

    id = 0
    for i in range(totalNumberOfCars):
        direction = randint(0, 1)
        time3 = randint(5, 7)

        car = Car(time3, direction, ''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for z in range(4)), id)
        id += 1
        carsList.append(car)
    random.shuffle(carsList)
    car_cnt = 0
    for car in carsList:
        car.idx = car_cnt
        car_cnt+=1
    # turn-on the worker thread
    bridge = Bridge()
    threading.Thread(target=bridge.workerR, daemon=True).start()
    # threading.Thread(target=bridge.workerR2, daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=bridge.workerL, daemon=True).start()
    # send thirty task requests to the worker
    for item in range(len(carsList)):
        if carsList[item].direction == 1:
            q.put(carsList[item])
            rc.append(item)
        else:
            ql.put(carsList[item])
            lc.append(item)
    # block until all tasks are done
    q.join()
    print("-------------. 2. > " + str(len(carsList)))
    print('All work completed')
```

OUTPUT (and the error):

```
Car(name: PJJG, time: 5, direction: 1)

PJJG arrived at bridge

PJJG crossing bridge

PJJG Exiting bridge

Car(name: BLSQ, time: 7, direction: 1)
Car(name: ZXPH, time: 6, direction: 0)
    
ZXPH arrived at bridge
    
    
BLSQ arrived at bridge
    
BLSQ crossing bridge
    
ZXPH crossing bridge  <<----!!!!! ERROR.. ZXPH with direction 0 cannot enter the single lane bridge because BLSQ with dir 1 is still crossing the Bridge.
    ....
```

Comment: Your logic doesn't seem to make much sense. It seems that you are checking if locks are locked and then assuming that they're still locked later. If the current thread isn't the one that acquired the lock, finding that another thread locked it does not guarantee that the other thread won't release the lock. So you can't rely on it to modify shared state.

Comment: I'd use concurrent.futures instead of threading as it handkes really well such complex things and make working with threads super easy.

Comment: Can you please post an example?

Comment: @David what should I do to modify the shared state?

Comment: @C96 Acquire the lock rather than checking if it's locked.